# Java: Create large text file with random numbers?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a text file with random numbers on each line.

I have managed to do this but for some reason the largest file I can seem to generate is 768MBs and I need files up to 15Gbs.

Ay ideas why this is happening? My guess is some sort of size limitation or memory issue?

This is the code I have written:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //Size in Gbs of my file that I want
        double wantedSize = Double.parseDouble("1.5");

        Random random = new Random();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("AvgNumbers.txt", "UTF-8");
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        int counter = 0;
        while(keepGoing){
            counter++;
            StringBuilder stringValue = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                double value = 0.1 + (100.0 - 0.1) * random.nextDouble();
                stringValue.append(value);
                stringValue.append(" ");
            }
            writer.println(stringValue.toString());
            //Check to see if the current size is what we want it to be
            if (counter == 10000) {
                File file = new File("AvgNumbers.txt");
                double currentSize = file.length();
                double gbs = (currentSize/1000000000.00);
                if(gbs > wantedSize){
                    keepGoing=false;
                    writer.close();
                }else{
                    writer.flush();
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you attempt to create a file beyond that limit?

Comment: it always stops at 768MBs no matter how big I want the file to be.

Comment: (sigh) Does your program just stop?  Do you get an error message?  Is there an exception?  Do you run out of disk space?  Does the CPU halt and catch fire?  What?

Comment: Nothing happens. The program just stops running. No errors no nothing. And I have plenty of disk space.

Comment: Hum actually your limit is 1.5Gbs, not 15Gbs. (1.5 x 10^9)

Comment: @vaugham I know but this is for testing sake. If it works for 1.5 ill go on to create larger files. The point I am making is that I cant even get it to create files larger than 770 MBs

Comment: It's working, but for starter you should use "(counter >= 10000)"

Comment: Thats strange, I have tried wantedSize as 1.0 and 1.5 and I keep getting 770MBs sized files. 

As for your comment on the counter; its incremented by one at each stage and checked. it will never reach over 10000 with (counter == 10000).

Comment: I just ran the code you have above and get a 1.5G file (1,465,232 KB, according to Windows Explorer).  How much disk space do you have?

Comment: Im running it on the University provided cloud service but according to them we should have 30 GBs of space each but there is no way for me to check exactly. Maybe there is a problem with their filesystem.

Comment: Some cloud services (like Google App's) have a special implementation of java.io. Have you tried on a desktop ?

Comment: Its working on my laptop but I didn't think to test on that as I didn't think it would be an environment issue especially as that the cloud environment we use is a lot more powerful than my laptop. We have our own cloud at the university built by the IS team so maybe they put some sort of restriction.

Comment: Thanks for everyones comments and help

Comment: Restriction, yes, possibly a resource limit. Run `ulimit -a` and look for a file size limit.

Comment: I would break point the line of code where you break the loop or add a debug message to show this is the limit.  Unless you are getting an IOException you have a bug in your code.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would code it.  It produces the size you want as well.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    //Size in Gbs of my file that I want
    double wantedSize = Double.parseDouble(System.getProperty("size", "1.5"));

    Random random = new Random();
    File file = new File("AvgNumbers.txt");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8")), false);
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        String sep = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int number = random.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            writer.print(sep);
            writer.print(number / 1e3);
            sep = " ";
        }
        writer.println();
        //Check to see if the current size is what we want it to be
        if (++counter == 20000) {
            System.out.printf("Size: %.3f GB%n", file.length() / 1e9);
            if (file.length() >= wantedSize * 1e9) {
                writer.close();
                break;
            } else {
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %.1f seconds to create a file of %.3f GB", time / 1e3, file.length() / 1e9);
}
```

prints finally

```
Took 58.3 seconds to create a file of 1.508 GB
```

Answer (score -2):

You never clean your StringBuilder, and it keeps accumulating all the random number strings you have stored. Just after you write do a clear().

Comment: I create a new instance of it at each iteration of the while loop (so for each line) so it should be cleared?